# Join two Table and union - no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have two tables:

Illustration

[image: enter image descri,ption here]

In the first table, I have the column NR which I join on the second table also on NR. This gives me the Infos I wanna know. But another step I have to take is that some people can also write this NR into a text field. So I perform a Filter to get only the numeric values and then perform a join on `t1.NR on t2.NRfromText`
This gives me two tables one with `NR on NR` and `NR on TextNR`.
Then I do a union between this two tables. I'm not sooo much into SQL but I would say that duplicates would not exits here? 
So the question here is then performing a join (inner join) `on t1.NR = t1.NR` only rows with this combination "will be in t1" and only rows with `t1.NR = t2.NRText` will be in t2? So then I do the union there won't be any duplicates?

Comment: please post also your query

Comment: are you doing `Union` or  `Union all` ?

Comment: and is your question about `Sql Server`or about `Oracle`? They are both very different please choose one

Comment: in any case I guess you can do a or on your ON condition in the join

Comment: I don't have a query yet. Maybe I expressed my self in a to complicated way. The basic question I have is that then performing an inner join on t1.NR = t2.NR only data rows with this being true will be shown? So when I later do another join on t1.NR = t2.NRinText and union this two tables will bring no duplicates?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Images are pretty bad way to share data. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 A much better way to share this can be found here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @ Mark: Yes but I did a union because later I maybe want to add an feature column like "Where the data comes from" and then give all data from t1 the attribute "save" and all from t2 "filterdata"

Comment: @GuidoG: I did a union, knowing that this will remove duplicates. But also performing a union all should not bring up any duplicates here because of the inner join?

Comment: @ASPYOK ah ok. But maybe you can try to prepare something temp like on http://sqlfiddle.com/. Regarding your first question it depends on your data. If the row with NR in the text doesn't have it in the NR column (and viceversa) then yes, you don't have duplicated rows

Comment: @Mark Yes from the business understanding there shouldn't be any rows with the same number in NR and NRText. But then performing an union like GuidoG mentioned should remove duplicates anyway even if there are some rows there NR and NRText are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Joining on text fields is not recommended. This will never be fast and is prone to errors. But, if your prefix is always the same I believe this will do it

```
SELECT DISTINCT data.* 
FROM
(
    SELECT t2.* 
    FROM [ActualTable1Name] AS t1
        INNER JOIN [ActualTable2Name] AS t2 ON t1.NR = t2.NR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.* 
    FROM [ActualTable1Name] AS t1
        INNER JOIN [ActualTable2Name] AS t2 ON SUBSTRING(t1.Text, 6, LEN(t1.Text) - 5) = t2.NR
) AS data
```